# How to set up org.hibernate.org.hibernate.FlushMode for a Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

How can I setup `FlushMode.ALWAYS` for all sessions in my Spring Boot app? 
It would be nice to have this setting in `application.yml`.

**UPDATE**

I tried with both in application.yml:

```
spring.jpa.properties.org.hibernate.flushMode: ALWAYS
spring.jpa.org.hibernate.flushMode: ALWAYS
```

However next code:

```
    Session ses = factory.openSession();
    ses.setFlushMode(FlushMode.ALWAYS);
    LOG.debug("!!!Session.FlushMode = " + ses.getFlushMode());
    LOG.debug("!!!NewSession.FlushMode = " + factory.openSession().getFlushMode());
```

gives:

```
DEBUG 47225 ---      : !!!Session.FlushMode = ALWAYS
DEBUG 47225 ---      : !!!NewSession.FlushMode = AUTO
```

Comment: You can try to add the following spring.jpa.org.hibernate.flushMode=ALWAYS
(of course in yml format).

Answer (score 8):

You need to add the following property:

```
spring.jpa.properties.org.hibernate.flushMode=ALWAYS
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I still get an exception on my `AccountRepository extends JpaRepository` method `save` when I want to save new rows which have foreign keys to my account. `saveAndFlush` works fine.

Comment: You asked about how to set the flush mode. The exception might be something else. To make sure the flush is set, check the `session.getFlushMode()` method.

Comment: @Loco Your question was about how to set that particular property which this answer actually answer. However apparently you wanted to ask a different question instead.

Comment: I can confirm that this does nothing (Spring Boot 2.4).

Comment: I can confirm that, this does not work in Spring boot 2.6.3